# Xamarin iOS - this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key NewButton

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I seem to be hitting a brick wall when trying to use a component called SideBarNavigation.

I have created a new ViewController in designer and given it a button called NewButton, when I go to load the app it crashes on this line :-

SidebarController = new SidebarNavigation.SidebarController(this, NavController, menuController);

RootViewController.cs

```
using UIKit;
using SidebarNavigation;
using Inchcape.iOS;

namespace Inchcape.IOS
{
public partial class RootViewController : UIViewController
{
    private UIStoryboard _storyboard;


    // the sidebar controller for the app
    public SidebarNavigation.SidebarController SidebarController { get; private set; }

    // the navigation controller
    public NavController NavController { get; private set; }

    // the storyboard
    public override UIStoryboard Storyboard
    {
        get
        {
            if (_storyboard == null)
                _storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);
            return _storyboard;
        }
    }

    public RootViewController() : base(null, null)
    {

    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        var introController = (IntroController)Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("IntroController");
        var menuController = (MenuViewController)Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("MenuViewController");

        // create a slideout navigation controller with the top navigation controller and the menu view controller
        NavController = new NavController();
        NavController.PushViewController(introController, false);
        SidebarController = new SidebarNavigation.SidebarController(this, NavController, menuController);
        SidebarController.MenuWidth = 220;
        SidebarController.ReopenOnRotate = false;
    }
}
}
```

MenuViewController.cs

```
using Foundation;
using Inchcape.iOS;
using System;
using UIKit;

namespace Inchcape.iOS
{
[Register("MenuViewController")]
public partial class MenuViewController : BaseController
{
    public MenuViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        var contentController = (ContentController_)Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("ContentController_");



        //ContentButton.TouchUpInside += (o, e) => {
        //    if (NavController.TopViewController as ContentController == null)
        //        NavController.PushViewController(contentController, false);
        //    SidebarController.CloseMenu();
        //};
    }
}
}
```

Has anyone experienced this at all???